# Represent gift cards in a mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5

I've trouble finding out what the best solution is for representing a gift card in a mysql database. Basically how to translate into a table.

You may ask why because it is a simple task but I can't wrap my head around the residual amount of the gift card. Do you put an extra row for the residual amount and modify it each time the card is used or do you simply display the residual amount by taking the the value of the card and removing all time it has been used without storing the residual amount?

[Gift card to table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekTMm.png)

In the image above, I'm showing what I thought for resolving the problem. I'm not sure for the last row though. The gift card is supposed to be used for buying products.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I have no idea what a gift card is or how it works. maybe you could ask the question in a less specific way?

Comment: A gift card is just a card with an amount of money of it that you can only use in a specific shop. Like a gift card of 50$ you can only use on amazon @P.Salmon

Comment: you _could_ create an extra column (not row) for the card which stores the remaining balance. Or, whenever you need to know the remaining balance, you could calculate it as the original balance minus the value of any transactions which it has been used for. Arguably the second solution is less redundant, since we are not storing data which could be calculated based on other data, but equally if this is going to be large scale, and you're going to use this value a lot, you might find it's better for performance to store it, and update it each time a transaction happens.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that is what I was looking for. @ADyson
Yeah by row I intend column when table is created, it's only a row in sense of when you create the table.

Comment: Ah I see you mean the rows in the form in your screenshot. That's just whatever UI application you happen to be using to create the database...it's not one that is familar to me. But yes they will create columns in the database. Anyway glad my comment was useful, it's a decision you'll have to make based on your knowledge/assumptions/predictions about the usage of your application.